# Is there a way to make a onclick event in Google Slides using Apps Scripts for a scoreboard?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

So am trying to make a scoreboard thing for fun and I used this script which can make this function possible and this is where I get stuck the values are not updating when clicked on during presentatioin mode. What can I do to fix this problem?

I tried using this script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();

  slides.forEach(function(slide) {
    var shapes = slide.getShapes();

    shapes.forEach(function(shape) {
      if (shape.getText().asString().match(/^\d+$/)) {
        var action = SlidesApp.newAction()
          .setFunction('increaseNumber')
          .setParameters({ shapeId: shape.getObjectId() })
          .build();

        shape.onShapeClicked().setAction(action);
      }
    });
  });
}

function increaseNumber(e) {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0]; // Change the index as needed

  var shapeId = e.source.getObjectId();
  var shape = slide.getShapeById(shapeId);
  var text = shape.getText().asString();
  var number = parseInt(text);

  if (!isNaN(number)) {
    number += 1;
    shape.getText().setText(String(number));
  }
}
```

Tags

When I applied this and nothing happened when I clicked on the textbox so what did I do wrong?

Comment: `I used this script which can make this function possible' Would you please cite the source of the script.`  What troubleshooting have you done and what were the results? What does the Executions tab show?  How did you decide on `SlidesApp.newAction()`? -  `newAction` is not a method available to SlidesApp.